# Trouble deploying a MERN app to Namecheap's cPanel for web hosting

Tags: node.js, cpanel, shared-hosting, mern, namecheap

I couldn't solve a certain Heroku issue (image storage/retrieval) so I'm trying my hand at Namecheap.

I purchased a domain and web host server from Namecheap, so I can deploy my completed MERN stack app I made for a client.

App file structure:

```
AppName
|
--client        <<~~create-react-app
|
--middleware
|
--models
|
--node_modules
|
--routes
|
--uploads
|
--.env
|
--.gitignore
|
--package-lock.json
|
--package.json
|
--README.md
|
--server.js
```

- Set my domain's Nameserver to `Namecheap Web hosting DNS` (namecheap guide instructions)
- Ran `npm run build` in `/client` (did not do `serve -s build` though) to generate `/client/build`

*server.js*

```
// For Deployment
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
};
```

- Connected my git repo to the domain via `Git Version Control` cPanel option
- Uploaded all my app files to cPanel `File Manager` (done automatically by `Git Version Control`)
- Used cPanel's `Setup NodeJS App` feature

Setting up the NodeJS App requires a number of form fields:

```
NodeJS version: 12.19.1           <<~~slightly higher than mine, their support team advised me to do that

Application mode: Production

Application root: repositories/AppName           <<~~path from the cPanel File Manager

Application URL: my-domain.com

Application Startup File: repositories/ChrisPortfolio/client/build/index.html           <<~~this has been a guessing game, more notes below
```

As for `Application Startup File`, I tried `server.js` and experimented with a few things here.

Everything I tried led to, visiting the app in the browser and hitting a "Not Found" page.

With `repositories/ChrisPortfolio/client/build/index.html` however, the app says "It works!" and displays the Node version I selected, but.. it doesn't show the actual app.

There is an option to run `npm install` from inside the cPanel `NodeJS` dashboard, and I made sure to do that.

I think perhaps I need to have it run `npm install` inside the `/client` directory as well, but the dashboard does not let you choose from where you wish to run the command.

Anyways, this is where I'm at.  Hopefully this is familiar to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Solved deployment by:

cPanel's Git Version Control option to clone my repo, creating `/home/username/repositories/appname` directory in my File Manager

After running `npm run build` in my `/client`, directly uploading the contents of `/build` to `/home/username/public_html` (it needs `index.html` at the root of this folder)

cPanel's Setup NodeJS App feature, referencing the directory mentioned above as Application Root, and `server.js` as Application Startup File

App is now deployed.